# AppFabric 1.1 for session state cache on a .net 2.0 application

Tags: session-state, appfabric, appfabric-cache

Is it possible to setup session state caching for a .net 2.0 application? I was able to get it work with a .net 4.0 app but not having any luck with 2.0.

If i base the provider on the Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache it fails because its too new, if i try to do it off the Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider it complains about the format of the web.config pointing at the type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider".

Is this even possible? can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppFabric Session State Provider 1.1 (`Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.dll`) requires .net 4 and adds many new features. You can see how to configure it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh361711%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) but there is no way to use it as a state provider for a .net 2.0 web site.

Hopefully, AppFabric Session State Provider 1.0 (`Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll`) is compatible with AppFabric 1.1. You just have to be carefull on the web.config because the configuration section is not the same.

Here is a very basic web.config :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>

  <!--configSections must be the FIRST element -->
  <configSections>
     <!-- required to read the <dataCacheClient> element -->
     <section name="dataCacheClient"
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection,
            Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         allowLocation="true"
         allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </configSections>

  <!-- cache client -->
  <dataCacheClient>    
    <!-- cache host(s) -->
    <hosts>
      <host
         name="YOURSERVERHERE"
         cachePort="22233"/>
    </hosts>
  </dataCacheClient>

  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
      <providers>
        <!-- specify the named cache for session data -->
        <add 
          name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" 
          type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSessionStoreProvider" 
          cacheName="NamedCache1"
          sharedId="SharedApp"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```